# Support for mapping of byte[]

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

Our entity contains the field `byte[] fileContent`.

Does not seem like spring-data-jdbc is saving it in DB; actually only 1 byte is persisted, and not the whole array.

Is there a way to persist binary content using Spring Data JDBC?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now there isn't. But it will be possible using `byte[]` in the not to far future. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-327 and https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-332